# Resolving js and css urls affected by app.Map in ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am implementing multi-tenancy based on the first folder segment of the request url.
As such I'm configuring each tenant separately by branching with IApplicationBuilder like this:

```
PathString path = new PathString("/somefolder");
app.Map(path,
branchApp =>
{
   // code goes here to configure the branch
}
```

as a result of this if my view has a link with url /Home/About for example, it automatically is adjusted to be relative to the folder I branched on when I visit /somefolder, ie the links change to /somefolder/Home/About, somefolder/Home/Contact etc

This was kind of unexpected to me but actually helpful.
But also if my view has

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
<script src="~/js/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
```

those now resolve to /somefolder/css/site.css and /somefolder/js/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js

which is not what I want.

Is there some way I can change this behavior for js and css but keep it for navigation links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. At least, not easily: when using `app.Map`, it automatically sets `HttpContext.Request.PathBase` with the path parameter you specified, which causes the exact behavior you're seeing (it's basically a "virtual directory" equivalent).

The best option is to stop using virtual path links (`~/`) and replace them by standard root-relative links (`/`), that are not processed by Razor and MVC.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css" />
<script src="/js/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: the problem with that is that some people will install my app as a virtual directory in IIS instead of as a root site which will resolve incorrectly. My plan is that folder tenants will only be supported if the main site is a root level site not a virtual directory. I need it to work at least for a single site deployed in a virtual directory without any additional tenants configured which means it needs ~/. I wonder can I implement some kind of custom url helper and add my own logic to resolve like @Url.Content(..) but plugin some custom code somehow?

Comment: Sure, you can provide your own `IUrlHelper` and use `Url.Content`: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/UrlHelper.cs#L111, though it may seem a bit hacky. Just create your own helper and register it via `ConfigureServices` and it should work. That said, I'm not sure you could use the automatic `~` resolution like the one you can use with script and link currently, since it's probably a Razor feature and not a MVC one. You'd probably have to use `Url.Content`.

Comment: Another option might be to continue using `/somefolder/js/` generated links and add one `app.UseStaticFiles` middleware per branch.

Comment: adding app.UseStaticFiles per branch works great, but I don't understand why since the resources don't really exist at the folder path but they are found.

Comment: It works because the static files middleware doesn't use `PathBase` to resolve the physical path and continues to work exactly as if it was not in a branch. Note that using the static files middleware may have a performance impact, since IIS won't be able to use its native static files module anymore. Requests will necessarily be handled by ASP.NET 5's static files and not directly by IIS. That said, it will be able to use the SendFile extension, that will help increasing performance, but it won't be comparable to IIS's native module.